# Created list instance and content type on sharepoint production, how to import to solution and create definition?

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list

I created simple list and content type on production server. Now I would like to import that list and content type to visual server. Visual Studio solution should contains: list definition, list instance, content type.

I tried to create ListTemplate and manifest.xml contains objects definitions. How to extract it to solution files?

I tried to export site but it is slow and generates error

```
PS C:\Users\SP> $web.SaveAsTemplate("SPEKO", "SPEKO","desc", 0)
Exception calling "SaveAsTemplate" with "4" argument(s): "Error exporting the l
ist named "AcceptanceAgreements" at the URL: Lists/AcceptanceAgreements"
At line:1 char:20
+ $web.SaveAsTemplate <<<< ("SPEKO", "SPEKO","desc", 0)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not on a Publishing site, you could save the whole site as template. That would give you a WSP from which you could then extract your artifacts.